# Align divs to start at the same vertical line with varying widths

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am sure there is an easy way to solve this, but I'm at my wits end:

I have the following layout:

[image: Edit Dialog]

With the following simple CSS:

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px;
}

.label {
  flex: 0.5;
}

.field {
  flex: 1;
}
```

However, I want the fields next to Label 2 through 4 to look like this:

[image: Target Layout]

How can I achieve this? I want a maximum width of around 100px. If it set `max-width: 100px;` I get this:

[image: Wrong Layout]

Which I guess is from the `flex: 0.5;` I gave the label. I could obviously set the `margin-left` of the field to negative-something, but that stops working when I resize the window.

Thank you!

Comment: please include also the relevant markup and create a working snippet

Comment: also add your HTML please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to define the flex-basis of your label-element, in a responsive unit like %, as you intent to always have a "hard" left edge.

Like so:

```
flex: 0 0 20%;
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/sh-roen/pen/jOyVovo)

Comment: Thank you, this works and makes a lot of sense. I didn't realise you can set flex properties this way.

Comment: You're very welcome :)
A good resource i usually go for is the "[Complete guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)" on CSS-Tricks whenever things get a little more complicated.